# Mesh Clipping Into Itself (Toplogy related?)

Tags: modeling

Newbie to modeling in Blender here. I was modeling an armor piece with a sort of etched panel line on the front, but I ran into an issue where the panel line ends. The left side looks good, but the right side is having some sort of strange issue I can't seem to solve. The normals are facing the correct direction, and adding additional edge loops didn't solve the problem. It is especially problematic after subdividing/soldifying.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Sure thing! Here's a link:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j96N8gy2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j96N8gy2/)

Thanks for letting me know how to upload it. New to the stack exchange here, as you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Cornvius has said, there isn't enough room for a Solidify Modifier. To demonstrate look what happens as you increase the thickness. Notice that the geometry starts to overlap.

[image]

What you could do is dissolve this vertex. Or try to make other topology changes and test the result by gradually increasing the thickness to see the problem. It's easy trial and error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry it was such a simple question. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The red angle is a lot sharper than the green one, there isn't enough room for the solidified faces to not overlap. To fix that you'd have to introduce another edge loop on the blue line and move it forwards a bit so the red angle is not as sharp. The blue line can be a lot closer to the angle, the point is just no not make it as sharp

It could also be that the these vertices are not on the same level and you need to flatten them by scaling them to 0 on the Z axis
[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help. I did add an extra edge loop, and the vertices are leveled on the Z axis. However, I'm still getting some strange clipping which is visible from the bottom. I forgot to mention, but this model has no creasing as well. I can upload the file if needed. Thanks again.

Images Here:
https://i.imgur.com/pHJRyHI.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/zJCLWss.jpg

Comment: Upload the file if you can. To me it looks like the angle is still too sharp. Maybe try adding another edge able the one you added

Comment: Thanks again for your help, apologies for the delay. Was having trouble figuring out how to best upload the file. I've been trying to mess with the order of the modifiers, but still am having some issues. 

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=j96N8gy2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/j96N8gy2/)